# What does the regular expression search/seplace pattern do?

Tags: c#, regex

What does the `<matcher>?()` regular expression do when used in the context of a search replace?

```
string input = "z=""(?<matcher>([a-z]{3,15}))"""
string pattern = z="cat"
string replacement = @"<ANIMAL>${matcher}</ANIMAL>";
string formattedOutput = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

The formattedOutput will be "cat" after the expression has evaluated.

Comment: Your code (a) does not compile and (b) makes no sense. Voting to close.

Comment: Are you sure you are not swapping `input` with `pattern`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of errors...

Here is the correction:

```
        string pattern = @"z=\""(?<matcher>([a-z]{3,15}))\""";
        string input = @"z=""cat""";
        string replacement = @"<ANIMAL>${matcher}</ANIMAL>";
        string formattedOutput = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);

        Console.WriteLine(formattedOutput);
```

`?<matcher>` is just a named group. You can pick any name. For example the following is equivalent:

```
        string pattern = @"z=\""(?<WHATEVER>([a-z]{3,15}))\""";
        string input = @"z=""cat""";
        string replacement = @"<ANIMAL>${WHATEVER}</ANIMAL>";
        string formattedOutput = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);

        Console.WriteLine(formattedOutput);
```